# Visa requirements check tool (or map) for holders of multiple passports/citizenships

Tags: dual-nationality, timatic

There are a few public pages that allow performing a Timatic visa check, such as [this one on the Emirates website](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/). Are there any that accept multiple passports and show all the results at once? I don't need them to process the results for me and tell me the best passport to use - I can do that myself - just show me all the results without making me submit the form multiple times.

Similarly, Wikipedia has great [visa requirements maps](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Maps_showing_visa_requirements) by country of citizenships. Are there any tools that would generate such a map for multiple citizenships? (How does Wikipedia even get the data for those maps - is it automated or human volunteers checking Timatic manually?)

Answer (score 6):

[TravelDoc](https://www.traveldoc.aero/) is a Timatic lookup site which allows you to specify multiple different types of travel documents, including multiple passports.  It doesn't seem to specify which passport to use, it just tells you whether you're good to go, and what other requirements there are.

[image]

To test I entered a single passport traveling to a country I knew required a visa, and it asked whether I had any other travel documents (as I hadn't specified that I had a visa for that country).  I then went back and selected "Add Other Travel Documents" and added another passport (which doesn't require a visa) and the results said I was good to go.

Comment: Thanks. That does allow entering multiple passports, but unfortunately it seems to mix together the "additional information" for all of them, when that only applies to someone with one of the passports. I tried setting the destination to one of my countries of citizenship, but also added another passport I hold, and while it said "visa not required" it also listed requirements for proof of accommodation and funds, etc., which obviously does not apply when entering on a passport of that country (it would apply on the other one).

Comment: @EM0 The "Additional Information" section doesn't seem to fully take the passport (etc) into account, as when I was testing it told me a US citizen needed a visa to visit the US if they had been to Iran (and other countries)...  It is possible that the Additional info section may not be fully specific to the travel documents, and is simply just broad additional information